# I am trying to call a method in a class that is within a class

Tags: java

My problem is that my message will not appear in my counsel window and I have no errors poping up

```
package test;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new start(); 
    }    
}

class start{

    Dialog dialog;
    int dude = 0;
    String[] text = new String[7];

    class Dialog {
        void dialog(){
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }    

    start(){
        new Dialog();    
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is very "smelly". Try to place all classes into separate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using `void dialog()` method rather `Dialog` constructor. Try this below:

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new start();

    }

}

class start
{

    Dialog dialog;
    int dude = 0;
    String[] text = new String[7];

    class Dialog
    {

        Dialog()
        {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }

    start()
    {
        new Dialog();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Dialog class there is no explicit constructor. Instead, you have method "dialog". This method is not called from anywhere. Rename "void dialog()" to "public Dialog", then it will be called when you create an instance of it via "new Dialog" and you will get what you expect.